# Wrap buttons ontop and in middle using Relative Layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

I would like to have a layout which is similar to

[image: Desired layout:]

Kinda feel guilty because I recently just asked a question about layouts but I had no idea that I needed to do this(nor did I know it was this hard), I have researched into View Layouts and I've tried use `layout.toRightOf` etc etc. I have the left/right arrows, I just need to add the up and down buttons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:game_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/pap.crowslanding"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <pap.crowslanding.GameView
        android:id="@+id/game_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        game_view:ballDiam="@dimen/ballDiam"
        game_view:cellWidth="@dimen/cellWidth"
        game_view:pixelHeight="@dimen/pixelHeight"
        game_view:pixelWidth="@dimen/pixelWidth" />

    <pap.crowslanding.MazeBall
        android:id="@+id/mazeball"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        game_view:ballDiam="@dimen/ballDiam"
        game_view:cellWidth="@dimen/cellWidth" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/right" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/down" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So essentially, just some insight on how I could add the up and down buttons within the same layout as to avoid layouts drawn onto my activity and overlapping

Comment: Did you try putting the buttons into a RelativeLayout instead of linear? I find RelativeLayout easier in such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that all your button images have the same height, so why not just use a `TableLayout`?
Keep the top-left and top-right cells empty, and in the other cells put your buttons.

Code (ommitting variables):

```
<TableLayout>
    <TableRow>
        <View />
        <Button>...</Button>
        <View />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button>...</Button>
        <Button>...</Button>
        <Button>...</Button>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I had no idea about TableLayouts, it works perfectly now and exactly how I wanted it

Comment: Glad I could help. Try to avoid relative views when you can.